# Como remover SMS após ter sido enviado?

Tags: android, sms

Estou tentando enviar o SMS através do SmsManager e, em seguida, apagá-lo dos itens enviados.
Estou executando o seguinte código:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(num.getText().toString(), null, msg.getText().toString(), null, null);
```

Para excluir o SMS enviado, testei o código abaixo:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/sent"), "address = ? and body = ?", new String[] {num.getText().toString(),msg.getText().toString()});
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/outbox"), "address = ? and body = ?", new String[] {num.getText().toString(),msg.getText().toString()});
```

Porém, estoura uma exceção **IllegalArgumentException**

Alguém sabe onde eu possa estar errando?